# How to delete zombie Safari open tabs in iCloud synchronization?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, safari, tabs

Recently I’ve restored my iPad from an iCloud backup and now Safari open tabs synchronization doesn’t work for it anymore.

There are two devices in my iCloud: iPhone and iPad. Both of them are running the latest iOS 14.5.1. When I try to access iPad Tabs from the iPhone, everything works well. When I try to access iPhone Tabs from the iPad, I get a long list of tabs that were closed long time ago and new open tabs do not synchronize. If I try to force delete these “zombie” open tabs (that do not actually exist on the iPhone) from the iPad, they keep reappearing in the list and nothing else happens. Currently opened iPhone tabs don’t show up on the iPad’s Safari list.

I’ve tried to delete Safari history as well as restart Safari synchronization (disable and enable it again), but it did not help.

I wonder if anyone encountered a similar issue and could suggest a solution without wiping the devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I’ve figured that out. If anyone else encounters such a problem, just re-login into your iCloud account on the device where these “zombie” tabs come from (on the iPhone as part of this question).

Comment: This will indeed clear out any existing zombie tabs, but does not prevent new ones from appearing. I went through this process last week, signing all of my devices out of iCloud and back in, and the problem went away for a few days, but now I have new zombie tabs that won't go away. Looks like it's just a bug and we'll have to wait for Apple to fix it properly.

Comment: Any sign that they have or will fix it? I'm barely seeing any acknowledgement from Apple that this problem exists.